# How to fix deprecated coroutines async, UI and await on android studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am working on a chatbot app using kotlin since last year. It has come to my attention some coroutines have been deprecated since last year and I didn't update it.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.android.UI
import kotlinx.coroutines.experimental.async
import org.jetbrains.anko.coroutines.experimental.bg
import org.jetbrains.anko.custom.async
```

My gradle file

```
  `implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15-coroutines:$anko_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-coroutines:$anko_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design-coroutines:$anko_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1'`
```

Here is the problem

```
async(Contacts.Intents.UI) {
    val response = bg {
        aiDataAIService.request(aiRequest)
    }
    if (response.await() != null) {
        sendMessageToServer(response.await())
    }else{
        Log.v("test", "didn't send")
    }
}
```

`Initially the app was compiling and worked very well, but now it ends up with an error whenever I try to compile.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val response = bg {
        aiDataAIService.request(aiRequest)
    }
    if (response.await() != null) {
        sendMessageToServer(response.await())
    }else{
        Log.v("test", "didn't send")
    }
}
```